# How to write data from Kinesis Data Analytics to DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

I am streaming real-time data with kinesis data streams into kinesis data analytics and I want to send the transformed data into dynamoDB. Currently it can be done by sending the transformed data into another stream which will trigger lambdas to write into dynamoDB.

But I was wondering if there is a way to directly call lambda from kinesis data analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially `Apache Flink` does not provide any `sink` connector for `Dynamo DB`.
Either you have to build your own `sink` connector or use some non-official ones. You can give it a try to the following one -

[Flink connector Dynamodb](https://github.com/klarna-incubator/flink-connector-dynamodb)